# JMeter 5.4.1: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed at the end of test

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

No matter how many threads I use, Jmeter shows errors in the end of the test. Just in the end - until that moment there are no errors. When threads are being closed, the last few of them are failed due to:

```
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException message:Non HTTP response message: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
```

or

```
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException message:Non HTTP response message: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
```

or

```
Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalStateException message:Non HTTP response message: Connection pool shut down
```

Three of them can be found in some of the failed threads most of the time.
I've tried almost every solution I've found in the net (including those on stackoverflow) but none of them fixed the problem. Below are links to examples I tried:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed 
https://www.xtivia.com/blog/fixing-jmeter-socket-errors

The setup of the script:

1. [bzm - Concurrency Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ztSD.png)
2. User Defined Variables
3. [CSV Data Set Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmYan.png)
4. [HTTP Cache Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcHDi.png)
5. [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fDLm.png)
6. [HTTP Request Defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOAMN.png)
7. [One of HTTP Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBCDS.png)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be connected with abnormal threads termination when your "Hold target rate time" ends.

Are you sure you're running test in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and following other [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

The options are in:

1. Ignore the errors as they are client-side errors
2. Introduce ramp-down so the threads will be terminated gradually, it can be done using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/)
3. Remove last requests which are failing from the .jtl results file using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)
4. Reach out to the [plugin developers and/or maintainers](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins) and report the issue there